# Как переустановить mysql службу

Tags: mysql, windows-7

Случайно удалил службу mysql из Windows 7. Все файлы и папки с mysql остались а вот служба была удалена. Как ее восстановить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустите консоль-cmd от администратора. Для создание службы используйте утилиту sc.
Формат команды:

sc  create mysqld binPath= "C:\mysql\mysql.exe --param=100"

Обратите внимание на пробел после = , путь укажите свой.